# what is the difference from"npm" and "npx --no-install"

Tags: npm, npx

The problem is not "npm and npx are what different is".
I know "npm" and "npx" what different is, but wonder in what scenario would I use "npx --no-install", not "npm".
please tell me, if you know anything about it.

Comment: What's the similarity? They're 2 different things.

Comment: Can you try and provide an example?

Comment: @JBallin npx enforces local modules in the same way that npm does。You know what's different, right? Expand on that